# Не работает кнопка рестарта, что делать?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я делаю свой первый проект на юнити 2д
и решил реализовать кнопку рестарта, посмотрел гайды, повторил всё как в видео но она не работает,
повторил на другом проекте и там она заработала. В чем может быть проблема ?
вся инфа ниже:

скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Restart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void RestartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

Скрины:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cDKX.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH8Xt.png

заранее спасибо !!!

Comment: проверьте, добавлена ли нужная сцена в BuildSettings->Scenes In Build. Если нет, то добавьте

Comment: В  BuildSettings->Scenes In Build сцена добавлена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте реализовать через OnMouseDown и обычный объект.